# Sending data in hotspot network

Tags: android, wifi, multiplayer, hotspot

I want to create an app same as Bombsquad. In which one device will create hotspot and any device will connect to it through wifi and then one will send data/number and that will be seen on every device.What should be used for achieving this
I think wifi direct will work for this?